# Enzyme not finding text in a div that is there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I have a test where I have some text rendered in a series Material-UI Cards. I supply the data for each card in a JSON array where each object looks like this

```
  {
        projectName: 'Project1',
        crc: 11305,
        dateCreated: '1/1/2020',
        createdBy: 'A. Bloggs',
        lastModified: '22/2/2020'
  }
```

In my enzyme test I find all the Cards and then make sure that each piece of JSON data has been rendered in that `Card` with the following piece of code.

```
const verifyThatAllCardDataIsRenderedCorrectly = ( cardsFound, dataItemsSupplied) => {
    dataItemsSupplied.forEach((dataItem, currCardIndex) => {
        for(let key in dataItem){
            if(key !== 'id'){
                console.log("Comparing CARD CONTENT ===>"+cardsFound.at(currCardIndex).debug() + " WITH =====> "+dataItem[key]);
                expect(cardsFound.at(currCardIndex).contains(dataItem[key])).toEqual(true);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

When the test fails I look at the debug output the relevant part of the `Card` within `cardsFound.at(currCardIndex).debug()` and it looks like this :

```
 <div className="makeStyles-projectPropertiesGridContainer-348">
    <div className="makeStyles-projectPropertyName-349">
      CRC
    </div>
    <div className="makeStyles-projectPropertyValue-350">
      11305
    </div>
</div>
```

and the value of `dataItem[key]` is `11305` so why does the assertion 
`expect(cardsFound.at(currCardIndex).contains(dataItem[key])).toEqual(true)` fail ??

[image]

The previous assertion for the attribute of `projectName` matches and passes!

Comment: `expect(cardsFound.at(currCardIndex).text()).toContain(dataItem[key])` should work

Comment: It does! Thank you so much. Perhaps you could put your comment in as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only wish to check for existence of text in a element, you can make of `text()` along with `toContain`

```
const verifyThatAllCardDataIsRenderedCorrectly = ( cardsFound, dataItemsSupplied) => {
    dataItemsSupplied.forEach((dataItem, currCardIndex) => {
        for(let key in dataItem){
            if(key !== 'id'){
                console.log("Comparing CARD CONTENT ===>"+cardsFound.at(currCardIndex).debug() + " WITH =====> "+dataItem[key]);
                expect(cardsFound.at(currCardIndex).text()).toContain(dataItem[key])
            }
        }
    });
};
```